# X only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here as function parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a loader function that exports an abstract class by the name of "Item". I then have a function that loads each instance of the item from a given directory, however to make sure that the loaded item is an `instanceof` the Item I want to load, then I need to get the `typeof` item I am loading in the loader method.

However by using  generics for the `load` method, I get the following error: `'Instance' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

This is my loader class and Item:

```js
export abstract class Item {
    // ... Different Item properties E.G Name
}

// Type for a collection of items or array
export type ItemCollection<Instance extends Item> =
    | Collection<string, Instance>
    | Instance[];

export class Loader {
    public async loadItems<Instance extends Item>(
        collection: ItemCollection<Instance>,
        item: typeof Instance, // < 'Instance' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
        dirs: string[]
    ) {
        // ... Load Items and check if it is instanceof "Instance", then assign value to the ItemCollection
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the `typeof` the `Instance` as a parameter, so I can check if the loaded items are an instance of it?

Comment: Please include a [mre] which can be pasted into a standalone IDE to test any suggested solution.  If there is some code that needs to run properly for you to accept an answer, that code should be in the question directly, not just as pseudocode.  Could you expand "Load Items and check if it is instanceof ..." into actual code?  And you should define any types/variables you introduce; `Collection` and `Instance` need definitions, or you should replace them with something else (maybe `Array` instead of `Collection`?)  It would also help if you show a call to `loadItems()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator applies to *values*, i.e. to *objects* or *instances*. It does not apply to *types*. It doesn't make sense to ask for the type of a type because types don't *have* types, they *are* types.

`Instance` is a *type*, it is not a *value*. You cannot ask for the type of `Instance`. If you want to ask for the type, you would need an *instance* of `Instance`.

But the type of an instance of `Instance` is just `Instance`, wo why don't you just use that?

```typescript
public async loadItems<Instance extends Item>(
    collection: ItemCollection<Instance>,
    item: Instance,
    dirs: string[]
) {
    // ... Load Items and check if it is instanceof "Instance", then assign value to the ItemCollection
}
```

Comment: In the loader, when I use the code: `if(!(value instanceof item)) //do something`, I get the error: `The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`

Comment: If you have a second question, please ask a second question.

Comment: No, thats the error I get when using item as just an instance. When using it as `typeof Item` for example, the error disappears, however I need it to use the given instance.

Comment: That line does not appear anywhere in your code, so the error cannot possibly have anything whatsoever to do with your question. Therefore, it is a completely different problem and should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: @abisammy: note that (value instanceof item) is NOT the same as (value instanceof Item) ; not the Uppercase "I" in the latter; lowercase 'item' is an object instance. Uppercase 'Item' is its class/type/constructor; (assignable to 'Function' and therefore usable as a right-side to instanceof)